# Retrieving Firebase data and assigning it to variables

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I'm trying to retrieve data from my Firebase data which I will then later use to help create my navigation drawer within the onCreate() method.

Within Mike Penz's [Material Drawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) which I'm using there's an option to specify account information such as name and email for the AccountHeader, so I'm trying to retrieve these details from my users table within my Firebase database before creating the navigation drawer.

Unfortunately using `addValueEventListener()` or `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` doesn't do what I need because the variables (userEmail, userRole, userName) are only assigned values after the navigation drawer is created.

```
if(authData != null) {
        firebase.child("users").child(authData.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot 
                Users user = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);                    
                userEmail = authData.getProviderData().get("email").toString();
                userRole = user.getRole();
                if (user.getFirstName() != null && user.getLastName() != null) {
                    userName = user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I've logged the values of the variables both inside this addValueEventListener method and after this method, so I know the variables are retrieving values but only after my navigation drawer is created and not before.

Hope I've provided enough information for someone to be able to help me get a solution to this problem, if I haven't just let me know what you need in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking about how you can add items to the `Drawer` after creation. It is posible, to **update**, **remove** and **add** items to the `Drawer` even after creation. For more info check here https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer#modify-items-or-the-drawer,

Edit:

```
    AccountHeader header = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header)
            .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                    //Handle Profile changes
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .build();

    Drawer drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withAccountHeader(header)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new DividerDrawerItem(),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings),
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_about)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    // Handle clicks
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .build();

    //Later
    header.addProfile(new ProfileDrawerItem().withIcon(bitmap).withName(name).withEmail(email), 0);
```

How does this work?

Comment: No, I asked how can I load the Firebase data before I create my navigation drawer.

Comment: You should not wait for the network call before actually creating the Drawer. It is better to create the Drawer first and then update and add more items to the Drawer after you load data from Firebase.

Comment: Is it possible to add the AccountHeader after the Navigation Drawer is built? Why can't you retrieve the data before the drawer is made? Seems like there's no way to retrieve the data without using `addValueEventListener()` or `addListenerForSingleValueEvent() `

Comment: try this; add an `AccountHeader` with no `Profile`. Then after Firebase data, add the user profile to the header. (or a dummy profile, say the application's name, icon and developer at first and then the real data later when it becomes available)

Comment: "...Why can't you retrieve the data before the drawer is made?" - Because network calls are as fast as the users network speed...which may never load or take a really long time. But try it out and see if the app can function well even with that, say maybe the user doesn't need the `Drawer` till his/her info is loaded

Comment: Just tried to do what you suggested and I don't think it is possible, tried to implement building the AccountHeader after the data is loaded in the listener methods and it's causing a crash with the error 'please pass an activity first to use this call' which I've done. So after getting that error, I tried to build the entire navigation drawer in that method and it didn't cause any crashes but when the app loaded there was no navigation drawer.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your help. I take it reordering the navigation drawer would be possible under the same logic?